# Where to put Findby elements from PageClasses

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, pageobjects, findby

I am preparing testFramework and wondering if it is a good idea to keep all Findby objects in PageClasses e.g:

I have PageClasses:

```
public class MainPage extends BaseExtendablePage implements Dataaa {

@FindBy(xpath = photo1) WebElement photo1;
@FindBy(xpath = "//p/i/a/img[@src= 'http://demoqa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/pattern-14-300x237.png']") WebElement photo2;
@FindBy(xpath = "//div/i/a/img[@src= 'http://demoqa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/pattern-14-300x237.png']") WebElement photo3;
...
```

I tried something like implementing interface Dataaa and putting in it at least String from xpath's, id's... :

```
public interface Dataaa {

String photo1 = "//p/a/img[@src= 'http://demoqa.com/wpcontent/uploads/2014/08/pattern-14-300x237.png']";
}
```

Is it a good way or is there any better idea to keep these elements or how to move them to some different location?

Comment: Can you shed some light on how different is your `PageClasses` from `PageObjects`?

Comment: I don't catch your question :(

Comment: @DebanjanB I think they're meant to be the same.  To answer the OP's question, the locator defined in the FindBy annotation must be a literal or a constant, so if wanting to define a String, it would need to be `final String`

Comment: Also, `@FindBy(xpath = photo1) WebElement photo1;` would make no sense in any situation as it's self-referential

Comment: so leave it as it is or move Strings to interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our project we keep the elements in the PageObject it belongs to. If there are elements used in more pages, then we try to share them through common parents.

If you want to have the Strings/Locators stored separately, you can create a Constants class and store them as constants:

```
public class Const {

    private Const() {}

    public static final String PHOTO1 = "//p/a/img[@src= 'http://demoqa.com/wpcontent/uploads/2014/08/pattern-14-300x237.png']";
    public static final String PHOTO2 = "//p/i/a/img[@src= 'http://demoqa.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/pattern-14-300x237.png']";
...
}
```

Keep in mind Java conventions: constants should be defined with capital letters.